# How to remove first N bytes of a large file in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a big file about 10G, and i want to delete the first 10 bytes of this file.

If I use `ioutil.ReadFile()`, the whole file will be allocated to memory. This can't be done!

Another idea is that I read this file line by line. And after removing the data, I should write the remain data line by line. In this way, the memory can be saved, but if there exists a better way? Like `split` the `reader` or `split` the file?

Comment: For the second part of the question, as @icza mentioned, the best way to copy a file is to use `io.Copy()`. That method moves the data by chunks. https://golang.org/src/io/io.go#L363 for more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On most filesystems you can't "cut" a part out from the beginning or from the middle of a file, you can only truncate it at the end.

The easiest to achieve what you want is to open the source file, skip the part you want to strip off (use seeking), open the destination file and simply copy from the source to the destination.

For seeking (skipping), use [`File.Seek()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek). For copying between the files, use [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy).

This is how it can be done:

```
fin, err := os.Open("source.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer fin.Close()

fout, err := os.Create("dest.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer fout.Close()

// Offset is the number of bytes you want to exclude
_, err = fin.Seek(10, io.SeekStart)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

n, err := io.Copy(fout, fin)
fmt.Printf("Copied %d bytes, err: %v", n, err)
```

Note that the above code will get the result file you want in a new file. If you want the "new" to be the old (meaning you don't want a different file), after the above operation (if it succeeds) delete the original file and rename the new one to the old.

This is how you can do that final step:

```
if err := os.Remove("source.txt"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if err := os.Rename("dest.txt", "source.txt"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```